# Trouble understanding this Kaf HaHaim

Tags: books-generally, time, bread, mezonot-beracha

My friend asked recently asked me an interesting Hakira in Halacha. Is it better to eat Pat Shahrit Hamosi or Pat Shahrit Mezonot and go to the Mikve (because of a lack of time)?

I started looking through some Mefarshim on the S"A where it discusses Pat Shahrit and was looking for some who allow eating Mezonot (not a Keviat Seuda). So I came across this [Kaf HaHaim 155:24](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=41181&st=&pgnum=358) which I can't really understand. I think it discusses the question, but I don't really understand what he is saying. If anyone can help me with this it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It seems Harav Musafi Shelit"a bediavad holds you can do Mezonot.

Comment: You're more likely to get an answer if you include the actual text of the Kaf HaHaim in your question.

Comment: "The question is widely applicable to a large audience. A detailed canonical answer is required to address all the concerns."  ?????

Comment: @DoubleAA I dunno!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> דמדברי  הש״ס משמע דבסתם  פת  מיירי כל שמסיר הרעבון

this translates to "from the words of the Gemara it is understood that when it says Pas, Pas = anything that takes away hunger"

Based on this eating crackers or cereal would suffice for Pas Shacharis.

[Rabbi Monsour](http://www.dailyhalacha.com/Display.asp?ClipDate=1/27/2006) brings in the name of HaRav Bentzion Abba Shaul that one fulfills this obligation also with other baked grain products, such as a cake or a danish.

[Halachically Speaking Vol 4 Issue 2](http://www.thehalacha.com/attach/Volume4/Issue2.pdf) says

> However, many say one is not required to eat  actual bread, and any
>   food one eats in the  morning is sufficient, as long as it is filling
>   (Eishel Avraham Butchatch 155). Some say one should be careful to have
>   a food  that is Mezonos (Pri Megadim M.Z. 1, Kaf Ha’chaim 23, Ohr
>   L’tzyion  2:10:6, Rivevos Ephraim 3:590:21, 35).